# GridStack with VUE element is not reactive

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, gridstack

I want to add VUE components to a GridStack but the rendered components are not reactive.

Here is a CodePen with the issue: https://codepen.io/adelriosantiago/pen/qBaXjrr?editors=1010

GridStack only accepts HTML so what I do is to create a new Vue instance with `let instance = new gridStackItem();` and then `instance.$mount();` to get the compiled HTML in `instance.$el`.

I then proceed to `addWidget` as per [GridStack's documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gridstack). The added elements are indeed correctly compiled (see how "SUBTEXT" text is there) however **these component are "dead"** (not reactive) and it is not possible to change them text through the `input` (see image below).

[image]

#### How can I make these components reactive?

Answer (score 1):

I created `div` element

```
let instance = new gridStackItem();
      
let div = document.createElement('div');
div.id = Math.random().toString(24).substring(8) // define id to access it later
      
instance.$mount(div);
```

and put the `div` as content in your `addWidget`

```
let widget = this.grid.addWidget({
  x: Math.round(Math.random() * 5),
  y: Math.round(Math.random() * 5),
  w: 4,
  h: 2,
  content: div.outerHTML
});
```

then appended your component instance as `div` child

```
document.getElementById(div.id).appendChild(instance.$el)
```

and it worked! The trick is using `div` as a connector between `widget` and `instance`, Here is the updated [Codepen](https://codepen.io/MNSY22/pen/LYRzGpQ)